# Слайдер типа "было-стало"

Tags: html, css, слайдер

Возник вопрос,как сделать слайдер на мобильной версии сайта такого типа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы при переключении менялась картинка.
И можно ли сделать, чтобы при переходе на планшетный и десктопный режимы, этот слайдер перестраивался в такой вот "ползунок".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/jotform/before-after.js

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin по-моему заголовок очень даже конкретный и легко ищущийся, картинка являтся здесь необязательным дополнением для пояснения сути вопроса

Comment: Если скажете, как вам лучше этот вопрос описать -я опишу. Просто я добавил картинки, чтобы наглядно показать, что именно требуется.